# Divide a number by x without using /, %, and *

Tags: verilog, math

I want to design and implement hardware in HDL (verilog) to perform division by 3, 5, and 7 specifically. The aim is to achieve this operation in a single cycle. Are there any general methods to perform this computation without using /, *, and % operators?

Comment: What study have you already done on this subject? What references to papers do you already have in hand? For example, did you find and read [this](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/courses/cs345/divideby3.xhtml)?

Comment: Ranging comparisons and look up tables.

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question.  No sane designer designs division algorithm to perform division in a single cycle unless it is for some super slow processor. You can do basic research on pipelined multiplication division algorithms on journals, youtube etc.

Comment: Please edit your question and detail what the numerical range (not just the bit) is of your division arguments and your clock frequency.

Comment: If you read @jp314 answer below you realize that you can implement certain extensive algorithms in a single combinatorial path. While that would probably qualify as "single clock cycle" what use would it be if you can do it only at 10 MHz ? After all, pipelining such calculations is precisely there to increase throughput for such long algorithms.

Comment: [ Question has been re-closed as "needs details* since the previous closing as a duplicate pointed readers to [this previous related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/602725) suggesting that there is an answer there - but there is (currently) no usable answer there either. If additional details are added here, or a usable answer can be added on either question, then the status of one question being closed as a duplicate of the other one can - and should - be reviewed. ]

Comment: @SamGibson That is fine. These kinds divisions -- not a simple lane change but modulo \$2^N{-1}\$ thing are often needed. Google doesn't make it exactly easy to find, but there has been material on this for a long time.

Comment: For a stupefying way to divide *multiples of 3* by 3, see Chin-Long WEY, Ping-Chang JUI, and Gang-Neng SUNG: [*Efficient Multiply-by-3 and Divide-by-3 Algorithms and Their Fast Hardware Implementation*](https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/23816/1/000331343200023.pdf) (it allows *detection* of non-3 *n* inputs, too).

Comment: Note that you can determine the remainder of a binary number modulo 1 more or less than a power of two somewhat fast, allowing combinatorial "remainder look-ahead" divisors much the same way carry look-ahead speeds addition.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform the division manually in binary (long division), you will see that it can be done by a regular array of combinational logic in a way that is a little more complex than addition-with-carry.

I have done this previously, just don't have the code available now.